# capistrano hangs at git clone

Tags: git, ssh, capistrano

With this configuration `cap deploy` always hangs:

```
set :application, "myapp"
set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/myapp.git"
set :branch, "mybranch"
role :web, "myvserver.stratoserver.net"
role :app, "myvserver.stratoserver.net"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www-test"
set :user, "philip"
set :group, "www-data"
```

One needs to enter a password 3 times:

1. For bitbucket
2. For myvserver.stratoserver.net. And always this seems to produce an error, making me enter it a third time...
3. I enter it and everything just hangs

On the server side `ps ax` gives:

```
 3116 ?        Ss     0:00 sh -c git clone -q https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/myapp.git /var/www-test/releases/201204281610
 3117 ?        S      0:00 git clone -q https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/myapp.git /var/www-test/releases/20120428161055
 3118 ?        S      0:00 git-remote-https https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser/myapp.git https://myuser@bitbucket.org/myus
```

The full capistrano output is here: http://pastebin.com/Ffqpqq7y

Comment: I had faced the same issue and my issue was concerned with ssh-keys.I had regenerated the ssh-keys and got it working.Hope it helps..

Comment: Actually the whole configuration is currently without ssh keys. But actually I'll change that now.

Comment: Yes let me know.Try debugging using ssh -V.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, cap doesn't hang anymore. Though it shows an authentication error now - but that's much better than freezing

Comment: I have made my comment into an answer.You can accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same issue and my issue was concerned with ssh-keys.I had regenerated the ssh-keys and got it working.Hope it helps..

Comment: After all I now use ssh keys and your solution works!  (+ I had to login one time manually via ssh, do a clone on the remote machine and say "yes" to accept key)

Comment: "do a clone on the remote machine and say "yes" to accept key"
who does accept which key when you do so?